How to use the given condition that $I$ and $J$ are non-empty to prove the given set equality (question in Terrence Tao analysis book)?
The full question is:
Suppose that $I$ and $J$ are two sets, and for all $\alpha ∈ I ∪ J$ let $A_{\alpha}$ be a set.
Show that $(\bigcup_{\alpha\in I} A_{\alpha})\cup (\bigcup_{\alpha\in J} A_{\alpha}) = \bigcup_{\alpha\in I\cup J} A_{\alpha}$.
If $I$ and $J$ are non-empty, show that $(\bigcap_{\alpha\in I} A_{\alpha})\cap (\bigcap_{\alpha\in J} A_{\alpha}) = \bigcap_{\alpha\in I\cup J} A_{\alpha}$.
I managed to prove the first equality without any issues, but when it comes to the second equality, my proof never used the fact that $I$ and $J$ must be non-empty.
My proof:
Now, we show that if $I$ and $J$ are non-empty, then $(\bigcap_{\alpha\in I} A_{\alpha})\cap (\bigcap_{\alpha\in J} A_{\alpha}) = \bigcap_{\alpha\in I\cup J} A_{\alpha}$.

First, we show that $(\bigcap_{\alpha\in I} A_{\alpha})\cap (\bigcap_{\alpha\in J} A_{\alpha})\subseteq \bigcap_{\alpha\in I\cup J} A_{\alpha}$.

Let $x\in (\bigcap_{\alpha\in I} A_{\alpha})\cap (\bigcap_{\alpha\in J} A_{\alpha})$.
Then $x\in(\bigcap_{\alpha\in I} A_{\alpha})$ and $x\in (\bigcap_{\alpha\in J} A_{\alpha})$.
By definition of $\bigcap$ , $x\in A_{\alpha}$ for all $\alpha\in I$ and $x\in A_{\alpha}$ for all $\alpha\in J$.
This implies that $x\in A_{\alpha}$ for all $\alpha\in I\cup J$.
By definition of $\bigcap$, it follows that $x\in\bigcap_{\alpha\in I\cup J} A_{\alpha}$.
Thus $x\in (\bigcap_{\alpha\in I} A_{\alpha})\cap (\bigcap_{\alpha\in J} A_{\alpha})\implies x\in\bigcap_{\alpha\in I\cup J} A_{\alpha}$.
Hence $(\bigcap_{\alpha\in I} A_{\alpha})\cap (\bigcap_{\alpha\in J} A_{\alpha})\subseteq \bigcap_{\alpha\in I\cup J} A_{\alpha}$.

Now, we show that $\bigcap_{\alpha\in I\cup J} A_{\alpha}\subseteq(\bigcap_{\alpha\in I} A_{\alpha})\cap (\bigcap_{\alpha\in J} A_{\alpha})$.

Let $x\in\bigcap_{\alpha\in I\cup J} A_{\alpha}$.
By definition of $\bigcap$, it follows that $x\in A_{\alpha}$ for all $\alpha\in I\cup J$. This implies that for all $\alpha\in I$ and for all $\alpha\in J$, we have $x\in A_{\alpha}$.
Thus by definition of $\bigcap$, it follows that $x\in(\bigcap_{\alpha\in I} A_{\alpha})$ and $x\in(\bigcap_{\alpha\in J} A_{\alpha})$.
Thus, $x\in(\bigcap_{\alpha\in I} A_{\alpha})\cap (\bigcap_{\alpha\in J} A_{\alpha})$.
We have shown that  $x\in\bigcap_{\alpha\in I\cup J} A_{\alpha}\implies x\in (\bigcap_{\alpha\in I} A_{\alpha})\cap (\bigcap_{\alpha\in J} A_{\alpha})$.
Thus $\bigcap_{\alpha\in I\cup J} A_{\alpha}\subseteq(\bigcap_{\alpha\in I} A_{\alpha})\cap (\bigcap_{\alpha\in J} A_{\alpha})$.

Since $(\bigcap_{\alpha\in I} A_{\alpha})\cap (\bigcap_{\alpha\in J} A_{\alpha})\subseteq \bigcap_{\alpha\in I\cup J} A_{\alpha}$ and $\bigcap_{\alpha\in I\cup J} A_{\alpha}\subseteq(\bigcap_{\alpha\in I} A_{\alpha})\cap (\bigcap_{\alpha\in J} A_{\alpha})$, it follows that $(\bigcap_{\alpha\in I} A_{\alpha})\cap (\bigcap_{\alpha\in J} A_{\alpha}) = \bigcap_{\alpha\in I\cup J} A_{\alpha}$.                                                        $\square$

My question: Where in the proof should I have used the fact that $I$ and $J$ are non empty sets? Also, is this fact strictly necessary? The statement seems vacuously true if the sets were empty (although I am not sure of this)

The issue is with the "big union operation" in general: what happens when $A$ is empty? $\bigcap A= \bigcup \emptyset$ (according to the def) must be $\text V$ the "universal set".

I suspect you need it in the line beginning "Let $x \in$ ..." which is followed by an intersection indexed by $I$. What does Tao say about an intersection over an empty set of sets?

Recall Tao's definition of the intersection of a family of sets:

We can similarly form intersections of families of sets, as long as the
index set is non-empty. More specifically, given any non-empty set $I$, and given an assignment of a set $A_α$ to each $α ∈ I$, we can define the
intersection $\bigcap_{α∈I} A_α$ by first choosing some element $β$ of $I$ (which we can do since $I$ is non-empty), and setting
$$\bigcap_{α∈I} A_α := \{x ∈ A_β : x ∈ A_α \text{ for all  }α ∈ I\}, \tag{3.3}$$
which is a set by the axiom of specification. This definition may look like
it depends on the choice of $β$, but it does not (Exercise 3.4.9). Observe
that for any object $y$,
$$y ∈ \bigcap_{α∈I} A_α \Longleftrightarrow
 (y ∈ A_α \text{ for all  } α ∈ I) \tag{3.4}$$
(compare with (3.2)).

Why does Tao not define the intersection of the empty family indexed by $I = \emptyset$?
Well, which set should $E = \bigcap_{\alpha \in \emptyset}A_\alpha$ be? If you look at $(3.4)$ it should have the property that an object $y$ belongs to $E$ iff $y  \in A_\alpha$ for all $\alpha \in \emptyset$. Since there are no such $\alpha$, this condition is vacuously satisfied, thus all objects should belong to $E$. Does there exist a set containing all objects? No.
But perhaps we can make a choice for $E$, for example$E = \emptyset$? This would violate $(3.4)$, but so be it. In that case we would definitely also violate the rule $(\bigcap_{\alpha\in I} A_{\alpha})\cap (\bigcap_{\alpha\in J} A_{\alpha}) = \bigcap_{\alpha\in I\cup J} A_{\alpha}$. To see this let $I = \emptyset$, $J = \{0\}$ and $A_0$ be any set disjoint from $E$. Then
$$(\bigcap_{\alpha\in \emptyset} A_{\alpha})\cap (\bigcap_{\alpha\in J} A_{\alpha}) =  E \cap A_0 = \emptyset \ne A_0 = \bigcap_{\alpha\in J} A_{\alpha}. $$
Thus it has good reasons that Tao does not define the "empty intersection".
If one works with subsets $A_\alpha$ of a given set $S$, then one can modify Tao's definition to
$$\bigcap_{\alpha\in I} A_{\alpha} = \{x \in S \mid x \in A_\alpha \text{  fior all } \alpha \in I\} \subset S.$$
With this definition $\bigcap_{\alpha\in \emptyset} A_{\alpha} = S$.
Perhaps one should not use the notation $\bigcap_{\alpha\in I} A_{\alpha}$ in that case (as it not the same as Taos's intersection), but something like $\bigcap^S_{\alpha\in I} A_{\alpha}$. Anyway, it is easy to see that for $I \ne \emptyset$ on has $\bigcap^S_{\alpha\in I} A_{\alpha} = \bigcap_{\alpha\in I} A_{\alpha}$.
See also Empty intersection and empty union.

Thank you for the reply! Do you think Tao was concerned that I show all this in this particular exercise, or should I just use the fact that his definition already says that $I\neq\emptyset$?

@IgorMello Your proof is absolutely correct, but depends of course on the fact that $\bigcap_{\alpha\in I} A_{\alpha}$ and $\bigcap_{\alpha\in J} A_{\alpha}$ are defined which requires $I, J \ne \emptyset$. The essential part is that you can use $(3.4)$. Therefore: No, Tao did not expect that you deal with empty index sets.

When we want Union , we take some element $\alpha$ from $I$ to "generate" the $A_\alpha$ which will also occur when we take the same element $\alpha$ from $I \cup J$ to "generate" the same $A_\alpha$.
Hence we can account for all elements in "Union of Individual Unions" $\bigcup_{\alpha \in I} {A_\alpha}$ , $\bigcup_{\alpha \in J}{A_\alpha}$ along with "Combined Union" $\bigcup_{\alpha \in I \cup J}{A_\alpha}$ to get the first Equality.
When we want Intersection , let $I = J = \phi$ , then the Equality will work out to $\phi \cap \phi = \phi$ , no issues.
The issues will occur when one is empty while the other is not empty.
Let $J = \phi$ , then there is no $\alpha \in J$ , hence no $A_\alpha$ there , hence $\bigcap_{\alpha \in J}{A_\alpha} \equiv \phi$
Hence "Intersection of Individual Intersections" is $\phi$
Checking the "Combined Intersection" , we see that is some $\alpha$ in $I \cup J \equiv I$ , hence there is some $A_\alpha$ , hence $\bigcap_{\alpha \in I \cup J}{A_\alpha}$ is not $\phi$ , generally.
The Equality is lost.
Where you went slightly wrong ?
When you assumed there is some element $x$ : There is no such $x$ in the Case I listed here : The "Intersection of Individual Intersections" has no elements. The "Combined Intersection" will have some such $x$ , in general.
( Comments are useful : user "Ethan Bolker" has already hinted at that , while user "Mauro ALLEGRANZA" has highlighted some issues too )
